# website images not loading hostgator

Tags: html, css

hello my website not loading images i just upload it , it's 1 html file and 1 images folder and 1 css file and the images should show using css file with html no scripts or anything.. the image is in other folder i tried to take the css file to main folder not it's folder .. and tried to type
 `domainname/theimagefolderandformat`
after trying

```
.class{
other properties  
background:url('img/..');
}
```

but not working either this is my domain 
www.anazidevo.com

help and thanks

Comment: You should talk to HostGator support. Looking at your site, your CSS is correct, and when I follow the `url()` tags, I don't get a 404 but some kind of [broken image png](http://www.anazidevo.com/img/anazidevo.png). This may be a hotlinking prevention feature that you've accidentally turned on. StackOverflow is not your website hosting support line

Comment: Those are not image files.  I've download one of it - I really do not know what is it.  for http://www.anazidevo.com/img/anazidevo.png - The file's suffix is .png, but the file content begins with hex [09 50 4E] - not compatible with magic number of PNG files hex[89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Some of your markup is sloppy, like not using

tags for text. I'd suggest either taking the time to properly code everything from scratch or using a template, like Weebly or Twitter Bootstrap.

Also, make sure all of your image files are uploaded to the image folder on your server.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment until 15 reputation, thanks for making me even further from that.

Comment: I have upvoted the *one* answer you have made so far that I felt justified it, so you are a net beneficiary from me. It costs reputation to downvote. Answers must be relevant, accurate and answer the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for how to write a good answer.